# How to create nodes in the repository in the bootstrap phase

Tags: alfresco

Let i need to create a nodes in the alfresco repository at the bootstrap phase to use them later, how can i do that?

I use the .amp file to install the extension customization into alfresco.war, so i have 
module-context.xml and inside it i write an import statement refer to the bootstrap-context.xml which have a bean like this

```
<bean id="com.ds.module.extensions.Core.securityRequirementBootstrap" 
        class="com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.module.SecurityRequirementBootstrap" 
        init-method="init">
    <property name="nodeService">
        <ref bean="NodeService" />
    </property>          
    <property name="searchService">
        <ref bean="SearchService" />
    </property>        
    <property name="authenticationService">
        <ref bean="AuthenticationService" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionService">
        <ref bean="transactionService" />
    </property> 
    <property name="personService">
        <ref bean="PersonService" />
    </property>  
</bean>
```

and as you see the bean have set of properties injected from a spring framework.

SecurityRequirementBoostrap is a class and it like as this

public class SecurityRequirementBootstrap {

```
public void init() throws Exception{
    AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new RunAsWork<String>() {
        public String doWork() throws Exception {
            try {
                transaction = transactionService.getUserTransaction();
                transaction.begin();
                if(!authenticationService.authenticationExists("admin")){
                    authenticationService.createAuthentication("admin", new   char    [] {'a','d','m','i','n'});
                }
                if(!personService.personExists("admin")){
                    personService.createPerson(createDefaultProperties("admin", "admin", "admin", "admin@localhost", "admin"));
                }
                authenticationService.authenticate("admin", new char [] {'a','d','m','i','n'});
                NodeUtil.checkSecurityPreRequesite(searchService,nodeService);
                transaction.commit();
                return "";
            }
            catch(Throwable e){
                transaction.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }
    }, "admin");
}

private Map<QName, Serializable> createDefaultProperties(String userName, String firstName,    String lastName,
        String email, String password) {
    HashMap<QName, Serializable> properties = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>();
    properties.put(ContentModel.PROP_USERNAME, userName);
    properties.put(ContentModel.PROP_FIRSTNAME, firstName);
    properties.put(ContentModel.PROP_LASTNAME, lastName);
    properties.put(ContentModel.PROP_EMAIL, email);
    properties.put(ContentModel.PROP_PASSWORD, password);
    return properties;
}   


private NodeService nodeService;
private SearchService searchService;
private UserTransaction transaction;
private TransactionService transactionService;
private MutableAuthenticationService authenticationService;
private PersonService personService;
public static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SecurityRequirementBootstrap.class);

public PersonService getPersonService() {
    return personService;
}

public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
    this.personService = personService;
}

public MutableAuthenticationService getAuthenticationService() {
    return authenticationService;
}

public void setAuthenticationService(
        MutableAuthenticationService authenticationService) {
    this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
}

public TransactionService getTransactionService() {
    return transactionService;
}

public void setTransactionService(TransactionService transactionService) {
    this.transactionService = transactionService;
}

public NodeService getNodeService() {
    return nodeService;
}

public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
    this.nodeService = nodeService;
}

public SearchService getSearchService() {
    return searchService;
}

public void setSearchService(SearchService searchService) {
    this.searchService = searchService;
}
```

}

As you can see in the init method i aimed to authenticate the admin user and after that i will use a NodeUtil class to create the nodes required. NodeUtil is a big class but it is work fine regardless of bootstrapping.

In all cases i have an exception once the alfresco bootstrapped and the exception look like this

```
$ org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelException: 07220000 No registered audit data extractor exists for 'org_alfresco_module_dod5015_userRolesExtractor'.
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState.cacheAuditElements(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:524)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState.access$500(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:240)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState$1.execute(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:389)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState$1.execute(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:375)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:381)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState$2.doWork(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:416)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState$2.doWork(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:413)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:508)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl$AuditModelRegistryState.start(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:412)
at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.start(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:458)
at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.start(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:440)
at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.getState(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:221)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl.getState(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:165)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.model.AuditModelRegistryImpl.getAuditPathMapper(AuditModelRegistryImpl.java:201)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditComponentImpl.areAuditValuesRequired(AuditComponentImpl.java:232)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:129)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy56.authenticationExists(Unknown Source)
at com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.module.SecurityRequirementBootstrap$1.doWork(SecurityRequirementBootstrap.java:29)
at com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.module.SecurityRequirementBootstrap$1.doWork(SecurityRequirementBootstrap.java:1)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:508)
at com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.module.SecurityRequirementBootstrap.init(SecurityRequirementBootstrap.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1529)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1468)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

So, can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks
Mohammed Amr | Digital Series | Senior System Developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest not using the Node Service to do this.

If you look at how new system folders are added into Alfresco (during upgrades and fresh installs), they're normally done as ACPs. By using an ACP, you don't need to take care of the special cases during the bootstrap phase (when not all of the repo is ready, and not all the services are fully available). Instead, you just point your bootstrap context file at an ACP, which has the content and nodes, and away you go.

If you want a simple example for creating a folder, you could try looking at `/config/alfresco/bootstrap/scheduledActionsFolder.xml` in a standard install for a simple guide.